# Form won't pop up

Tags: javascript, html

I put a "Jotform" form inside my script and it won't pop up. When I click no the text (other 8b white) pops up but why isn't that the case for the yes button? I just want my form to simply show when someone clicks yes.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rf8Ux/

Here's the where the problem occurs:

```
if (q1 == "Yes") {
      document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<script type=text/javascript     src=http://form.jotform.us/jsform/32217646901149 />";
    } else if (q1 == "No") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "other 8b white";
    }
```

Here's the original Jotform code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://form.jotform.us/jsform/32217646901149"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't add a script like that, and once it's loaded you certainly can't remove it again, and on top of that the script you're trying to load has certain functions that only work on pageload, otherwise it will fail, so you should just load the script, and then hide and show the container with the form.

Comment: @adeneo how do you suggest I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div in your html and place the Jotform script in it.  Set the display to none.  Then

```
if (q1 == "Yes") {
    $('#divName').show()
 } else
    // do something e.g. $('#divName').html('other 8b white').show(); }
```

Here:[http://jsfiddle.net/KzFhY/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/KzFhY/)

Comment: It works perfectly but if you click no and then click yes again the form doesn't show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Following adeneo's advice,

1. place the original jotform script in between your head tag
2. use css to hide the form element
3. if using jquery, $("form element name").show(); onclick